# SFML + Opengl. У куба просвечивают стены

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

Каждый раз когда я пишу куб на SFML у него начинают просвечивать стенки.
Даже код который я взял из сети имел такую погрешность. В чём может быть причина?

Исходный код: [ПТЫРК~](https://gist.github.com/kenpower/4018118)

[image: Тот самый куб]

Comment: По идее у цвета стенок нет альфа-канала.. Даже проблемы и не вижу..

Comment: Скорее всего забыли включить или включили неправильно буфер глубины и тест глубины при отрисовке (GL_DEPTH_TEST, glDepthFunc и пр.)

Comment: Но ведь там в коде включен буфер глубины... Может проблема в sfml? На sdl такое работьало нормально... Но я намерен изучать именно sfml

Comment: Есть еще такой вариант проблемы и решения: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045843

Comment: О, заработало) Спасибо)